# Two different ways of solving $\int \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x} } dx$, yield different results. What's the mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I solved
$$\int \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}} dx$$

in two different ways. Apparantly, I am doing a simple mistake that I can't spot. Can you?

---

**$1^{st}$ Solution**

$$\int \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}} dx \quad (*)$$
Let $ u = e^x + e^{-x} $, therefore $dx = \frac{du}{e^x - e^{-x}}$

$$(*) \iff \int\frac{1}{u } du= \ln|u| + C = \ln|e^x + e^{-x}| + C$$

---

**$2^{nd}$ Solution**

$$\int \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}} dx = \int  \frac{\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}}{\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}} dx = \int \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)} dx\quad (**)$$

Let $ u = \cosh(x) $, therefore $dx = \frac{du}{\sinh(x)}$

$$(**) \iff \int\frac{1}{u} du= \ln|u| + C = \ln|\cosh(x)| + C$$

---

Therefore,

$$\ln|\cosh(x)| = \ln|e^x + e^{-x}| \iff \cosh(x) = e^x + e^{-x}$$ which is ***almost*** true

A fraction $\frac{1}{2}$ disappeared somewhere. Where?

Comment: The $C$s are not the same.

Comment: $\ln(\cosh(x)) =\ln(e^x+e^{-x}) -\ln 2$. That $\ln 2$ is being merged with $C$.